# org.primefaces.PrimeFaces.Dialog.showMessageDynamic(FacesMessage) - allow draggable option

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For dynamic dialogs created via org.primefaces.PrimeFaces.Dialog.showMessageDynamic(FacesMessage), is it possible for the resulting dialog to be draggable? Seems there are no options to configure this and I am forced to use p:dialog instead

Answer (score 1):

Never tested it myself but, if memory serves, there is such option, although you will need to add parameters.
edit: nvm turns out they describe it in showcase, have the link (halfway through site):

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/core/dialogframework?id=dialog-configuration

You will need to combine

```
DialogFrameworkOptions options = DialogFrameworkOptions.builder()
```

and

```
PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic(message, options, null);
```

where message is string instead of FacesMessage, which should't be much of a problem.

Comment: it appears that "message" is actually the outcome, which means I need to create a new jsf view and managed bean. for now i have just resorted to using a p:dialog temporarily